# Laravel homestead installed on windows, pushed to bitbucket, then cloned on a mac, DB migration error

Tags: windows, vagrant, homestead, laravel-5.5, php-7.1

[image]

I currently have Laravel homestead on windows (working on windows 10 and Windows 8)

I am using Laravel version 5.5.3, and I pushed this to bitbucket, and cloned the repo on a mac with Sierra 10.12.6

I have already checked around the questions and tried adding the port in the .env file, but the port is already there as 3360, and it's correct. The db name and pass are also correct. Does the mac user just have to download and use vagrant homestead? Is there an alternative to installing vagrant and homestead to migrate the database for a mac user?

I think part of the problem is that since I uploaded it to bitbucket and the mac user cloned it, it has some settings that are configured to having homestead, so I'm guessing the mac user needs to install those other programs (homestead, vagrant, and vmware).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. If the database is created via Homestead and the configuration in the .env points to Homestead then the mac-user needs Homestead as well.
Install the necessary software and try again with Homestead up on the mac.
An alternative would be to use another local dev-environment like XAMPP or MAMP or some other local server and database. If you do this you have to change the database-configuration in the mac-users .env-file.

Comment: Thank you, Tamali.